# Counting the Occurence of Hexadecimal Numbers - R

Tags: r

So I have a file which contains a large number of hexidecimal digits in pairs, and a 'NA'/missing data symbol of "??".

```
 A4 BB 08 6F E7 88 D9 10 11 12 AC CB C8 CC  #Row of data in the file.
 ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ??  #Row of missing data in the file.
```

I'm attempting to pipe all of that in  and get some insight into the frequency of each hexadecimal number from 0 to 256. So far I read it into a structure using the 'read table' command (call it test), and I'm really not sure exactly what to do from there. I've done a number of different things trying to suppress the lines with "??" in any column and then convert the rest to hex values and get something useful from this. If anyone can point me towards the tools I need to complete this task I'd much appreciate it.

Edit:
As per request the output of dput.

```
structure(list(V2 = structure(c(88L, 209L, 124L, 91L, 132L, 235L
), .Label = c("??", "00", "01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", 
"07", "08", "09", "0A", "0B", "0C", "0D", "0E", "0F", "10", "11", 
"12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "1A", "1B", "1C", 
"1D", "1E", "1F", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", 
"28", "29", "2A", "2B", "2C", "2D", "2E", "2F", "30", "31", "32", 
"33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "3A", "3B", "3C", "3D", 
"3E", "3F", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", 
"49", "4A", "4B", "4C", "4D", "4E", "4F", "50", "51", "52", "53", 
"54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59", "5A", "5B", "5C", "5D", "5E", 
"5F", "60", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67", "68", "69", 
"6A", "6B", "6C", "6D", "6E", "6F", "70", "71", "72", "73", "74", 
"75", "76", "77", "78", "79", "7A", "7B", "7C", "7D", "7E", "7F", 
"80", "81", "82", "83", "84", "85", "86", "87", "88", "89", "8A", 
"8B", "8C", "8D", "8E", "8F", "90", "91", "92", "93", "94", "95", 
"96", "97", "98", "99", "9A", "9B", "9C", "9D", "9E", "9F", "A0", 
"A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5", "A6", "A7", "A8", "A9", "AA", "AB", 
"AC", "AD", "AE", "AF", "B0", "B1", "B2", "B3", "B4", "B5", "B6", 
"B7", "B8", "B9", "BA", "BB", "BC", "BD", "BE", "BF", "C0", "C1", 
"C2", "C3", "C4", "C5", "C6", "C7", "C8", "C9", "CA", "CB", "CC", 
"CD", "CE", "CF", "D0", "D1", "D2", "D3", "D4", "D5", "D6", "D7", 
"D8", "D9", "DA", "DB", "DC", "DD", "DE", "DF", "E0", "E1", "E2", 
"E3", "E4", "E5", "E6", "E7", "E8", "E9", "EA", "EB", "EC", "ED", 
"EE", "EF", "F0", "F1", "F2", "F3", "F4", "F5", "F6", "F7", "F8", 
"F9", "FA", "FB", "FC", "FD", "FE", "FF"), class = "factor"),
```

There are a number of other columns as well. I left them off as they have the same ~257 values for labels give or take a hex value here or there.

as.hexmode(names(test)) resulted in the same issue, couldn't coerce 'x' to hexmode.

Edit: Okay I had some success and I got it to do what I wanted it to do more or less.

First I wanted to merge the columns as I just wanted an overall count of the occurrences (this may even have been unnecessary)

```
test2 <- 
c(as.character(test[,1]),as.character(test[,2]),as.character(test[,3]),as.character(test[,4]), 
as.character(test[,5]), as.character(test[,6]), as.character(test[,7]), 
as.character(test[,8]), as.character(test[,9]), as.character(test[,10]), 
as.character(test[,11]), as.character(test[,12]), as.character(test[,13]), 
as.character(test[,14]), as.character(test[,15]), as.character(test[,16]))
```

Then I just wanted the counts of each value:

```
table(test2)
```

No conversion to integers or any such shenanigans necessary. I feel more than a little dumb, but oh well. I am still curious though if there's a better way to get the overall count across all rows and columns of each value as the way I did it seems clunky.

Edit:
The ultimate answer was (going with my original naming convention):

```
table(unlist(lapply(test, as.character)))
```

Thank you BondedDust.

Comment: Post `dput( head(test))` as an edit to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if you get some success with:

```
as.hexmode ( names(test) )
```

The output you offer suggests a table-object has been created and teh first row would be the `names` (in character mode) of the entries seen below those hex-characters. It remains unclear whether you are showing the the content of an external text file or output on the console so this may be a WAG.

```
> res <- scan(what="")
1:  A4 BB 08 6F E7 88 D9 10 11 12 AC CB C8 CC
15: 
Read 14 items
> as.hexmode(res)
 [1] "a4" "bb" "08" "6f" "e7" "88" "d9" "10" "11" "12" "ac" "cb" "c8" "cc"
> dput( as.hexmode(res) )
structure(c(164L, 187L, 8L, 111L, 231L, 136L, 217L, 16L, 17L, 
18L, 172L, 203L, 200L, 204L), class = "hexmode")
```

Comment: I misunderstood the thing I was doing. I correctly used the 'read.table()' method because the data I have is in a table format, but I needed to actually create a table from the resultant data frame. I edited my original post with what did the thing I wanted but it seems clunky and if you have any ideas for a more elegant solution I would appreciate it. Thank you for your time either way.

Comment: I sounds as though you could have done this: `table(unlist( lapply(test2, as.character)))`. It sounds as though the factor levels are different from column to column, so you first need to convert then to character mode in order to "collapse" them properly. You read R code from the "inside out".

Comment: Yup. That works. Thank you and apologies for my poorly articulated question.